# How much delay when sending message over socket

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I want to implement a client server over 2 raspberry pis connected directly to eachother via ethernet.  I want to send a message via socket from the PI #1 to PI #2 to tell PI#2 to take a image via the camera module.

How much delay is there from time I send message, to the PI receiving the message(and then taking the image)?  I need less than 20 milliseconds hopefully.

Comment: Try it and see. Maybe try measuring a round-trip time and half the result as that's easier than accurately synchronising clocks.

Comment: rpi has an ethernet port that supports a max throughput of 300mbps ... so it it cant go faster than that ...(which at a guess is less than the 50FPS you are asking for)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I didn't interpret OP's question as requiring 50 FPS - it sounded more like a single shot to me. Hopefully OP will clarify please...

Comment: good to know that rpi ethernet is too slow to do what i want!!

Answer (score 0):

The standard Linux command line tool `iperf` will do this for you.

On the server side:

```
iperf -s
```

On the client side:

```
iperf -c ip-of-the-server
```

`iperf` will output statistic on thruput.

client output:

```
iperf -c localhost
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to localhost, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 2.50 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 127.0.0.1 port 58950 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  37.2 GBytes  32.0 Gbits/sec
[sri@localhost ~]$
```

server:

```
 iperf -s
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 127.0.0.1 port 5001 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 59732
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  40.1 GBytes  34.4 Gbits/sec
```

There are plenty of options to help you tune the iperf test and get the info that you want.